# How can I write the pytest.main messages into a string?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

When I call pytest.main(...) in Python, it will display the unit test messages in the output window, such as

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.3.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: xxx, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: cov-2.5.1, hypothesis-3.38.5
collected 1 item

..\test_example.py F                                      [100%]

================================== FAILURES ===================================
_______________________________ test_something ________________________________

    def test_something():
>       assert 1 == 0
E       assert 1 == 0

..\test_example.py:5: AssertionError
========================== 1 failed in 0.60 seconds ===========================
```

My question is simply that how can I get the message above into a string object. The documentation doesn't say anything about this. And the what pytest.main() returns is only an integer that represents the error code.

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know pytest but you can try to redirect the standard output to a file. Something like this:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open("log.txt", "w")
```

After this you can read the file to get the strings. What do you want to do with the strings?